# How do I need to rewrite the SQL update statement subquery to select only a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I need to rewrite the SQL update statement subquery to select only a single row?

I have tried TOP 1, but that just updates all values to the TOP 1 select value.

Here's what I have:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE DBO.TRACKINGPROD
    SET LEV8 = (SELECT SUBSTRING(LEV2, 1, 
        (SELECT CHARINDEX('-', LEV2) - 1))
        FROM DBO.TRACKINGPROD)
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Results:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The statement has been terminated.

Sample from table:

Lev2 Column = A1011-000-XXXXX AHN - XXXXX v. XXXXX Rancho
Lev8 = Blank

My ultimate goal is to update Lev8 with everything to the left of the dash in Lev2 in the same row.

Comment: add a where clause, top 1 with and order by, or aggregate... only you can decided since you understand the data

Comment: Something wrong with yor paranthesis right now, 3 times -> "(" and 4 times -> ")" used

Comment: Which value do you want to update to? Add some sample table data and the expected result to your question. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: @jarlh I ultimately want to update Lev8 to have all of the Lev2 characters prior to the '-' dash.

Comment: If your in doubt Nathan, start with a select statement. And if desired result set is what your looking for change syntax for an update.

Comment: @junketsu Gotcha. That's what I had done, but my results were a list of the correct output, but apparently too many rows in regard to an update statement.

Comment: Thanks @scsimon

Comment: no worries, Yogesh had a better idea

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do it with single query :

```
UPDATE DBO.TRACKINGPROD
     SET LEV8 = SUBSTRING(LEV2, 1, CHARINDEX('-', LEV2) - 1));
```

You can also use `LEFT()` instead :

```
UPDATE DBO.TRACKINGPROD
     SET LEV8 = LEFT(LEV2, CHARINDEX('-', LEV2) - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh. That did it. So I had a subquery when I didn't need one.

Comment: @NathanHolmes. . . Your `subquery` has no connection with `outer query`. So, it would return all rows for each row of outer query when it execute. Hence, the error is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I read above in the comment I may have misunderstood the question. Still, in case someone comes accross this post I will provide my humble solution in which only the first row in the table gets updated and the second entry stays as it is.

```
declare @t table (lev2 nvarchar(200), lev8 nvarchar(6))

insert into @t (lev2, lev8)
values
    (
        N'A1011-000-DAVID AHN - Zavala v. Okokase Rancho',
        N''
    ),
    (
        N'A1011-000-DAVID AHN - Zavala v. Okokase Rancho',
        N''
    )

set rowcount 1;
update @t
set lev8 = substring(lev2, 1, charindex('-', lev2) - 1);

set rowcount 0;

SELECT * 
FROM @t as t
```

[image]